# How to backup files on mac when OS installation failed to finish?

Tags: macos, operating-system, backup, failed-installation

I run installation of OS on old Mac book Pro and the installation was not able to complete.

Is there a way to save my files, before reformatting the Mac?

Comment: Hi Shefy Gur-ary, great to hear you found the answer. But questions relating to using Apple devices (as opposed to programming) should be directed to the Apple Stack Exchange, [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I thought I lost my files, but found out that after getting to disk utility, you can go to:

File > New Image > Image from Folder

And this way save your file to an external Hard Drive, then open them in another Mac and backup. This really saved me, hope it would help you two because it took me forever to find this solution